# Ceiling of a number in JSTL/EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, ceil

In JSTL,

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${1.6}" type="number" pattern="#"/>
```

returns `2` and the following

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${1.4}" type="number" pattern="#"/>
```

returns`1` and I need `2`, **a ceiling of a number**.

Is there a direct way to achieve this in JSTL (or the only way to do so is by using an appropriate custom tag)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The default rounding mode of [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) that is used by [`<fmt:formatNumber>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html) is [`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN). There is no way to change that via any tag attribute. Just add `0.5` to the value when it's not an odd integer to make it to behave like [`RoundingMode.CEILING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#CEILING).

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${bean.number + (bean.number % 1 == 0 ? 0 : 0.5)}" 
    type="number" pattern="#" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${N+(1-(N%1))%1}" type="number" pattern="#"/>
```

where N is the name of your variable.

Regards

Comment: The good thing of this method is that you can easily turn it into floor rounding just by changing it to `${N-(1-(N%1))%1}`.

Comment: don't you mean ${N-(N%1)} @AxeEffect ?