# fmt:formatNumber rounding inconsistency

Tags: jsp, jstl

I don't know if it's just me, but

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="roundedNumber" value="2.5" type="number" pattern="#" />
```

gives me

```
<%-- ${roundedNumber} == 2 --%>
```

Do you know why formatNumber doesn't round this to 3?

*UPDATE*

It seems that if the number is ODD is rounded correctly, but if it's even number it's not.

```
2.5 will be rounded 2
2.51 will be rounded 3
3.5 will be rounded 4
3.51 will be rounded 4
4.5 will be rounded 4
4.51 will be rounded 5
... etc
```

Comment: Related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735545/ceiling-of-a-number-in-jstl-el

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought the cause might be the implementation of the JSTL by the container but the same thing happens to me.

I then read the [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library version 1.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr052/) specifications and in **section 9.7 fmt:formatNumber** in the paragraph entitled **Description** it says that a pattern string specified via the pattern attribute must follow the pattern syntax
specified by the class java.text.DecimalFormat.

So I looked up the java docs of [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and in the section entitled **Rounding** it states that by default that it uses the [RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) mode to round. This mode rounds a number towards the "nearest neighbour" unless both neighbours are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbour.

This then explains why 2.5 rounds to 2 (the nearest even neighbour) and 3.5 rounds to 4 (the nearest even neighbour).

Comment: very helpful last line. Thanks