# how to round a variable to two places if variable contains zero after decimal in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to round a variable to two decimal places using jstl.

for Example,
value=3.005 ==> 3.01
value=1.076 ==> 1.08

```
<c:set var="testAmt"><fmt:formatNumber type="number" pattern="#########.00" groupingUsed="false" value="${3.005}" /></c:set>
```

This way I get testAmt = 3.00.

but if value is `${3.015}`
testAmt = 3.02

so, I converted it by doing the following:

```
<c:set var="testAmt"><fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${3.005}" /></c:set>
```

but it doesn't seem to be rounding properly **only when variable contains zero after decimal.**

`value="${3.005}` ==> 3.00
`value="${3.015}` ==> 3.02

why formatNumber doesn't round 3.005 to 3.01?
How can i do this using JSTL ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313022/fmtformatnumber-rounding-inconsistency

Comment: This is what I needed. thanks