# Why JSTL fmt:formatNumber returns different result depending on value type?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, bigdecimal

### Outline

I am using Spring MVC and JSPs in web application project.
The JSTL is used to round the values to 2 decimals during display.

I have following java object:

```
public class AreaData {
    private BigDecimal area;

    public void setArea(BigDecimal area) {
        this.area = area;
    }
    public BigDecimal getArea(BigDecimal area) {
        return this.area;
    }
    // other currently irrellevant fields
}
```

Here is part where I set BigDecimal values under test in AreaData objects and pass to JSP:

```
List<AreaData> areas = new ArrayList<>();
AreaData a1 = new AreaData();
AreaData a2 = new AreaData();
a1.setArea(new BigDecimal("4.565"));
a2.setArea(new BigDecimal("4.575"));
areas.add(a1);
areas.add(a2);
model.addAttribute("areas", areas);
```

Here is part of JSP. I have 4 columns displaying unformatted and differently formatted area values:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Actual</th>
            <th>BigDecimal</th>
            <th>doubleValue()</th>
            <th>floatValue()</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="areaData" items="${areas}">
            <tr class="areaRow">
                <td>${areaData.area}</td>
                <td><fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${areaData.area}"/></td>
                <td><fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${areaData.area.doubleValue()}"/></td>
                <td><fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${areaData.area.floatValue()}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Problem

Outputs on jsp are the following:

```
Actual  BigDecimal  doubleValue()  floatValue()
4.565   4.56        4.57           4.57
4.575   4.58        4.58           4.57
```

From following link I learned that fmt:formatNumber uses [RoundingMode:HALF_EVEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313022/fmtformatnumber-rounding-inconsistency) which explains the BigDecimal column outputs.

### Question

Why passing doubleValue() or floatValue() to jstl formatNumber gives different result than BigDecimal?