# JSP tag library <fmt:formatNumber> tag rounds the fractional Value

Tags: jsp, tags

Lets take following Cases

Case I:

> double d = 123.994;
>
> <fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${d}" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
>
> Result: 123.99

Case II:

> double d = 123.996;
>
> <fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${d}" maxFractionDigits="2"
>   />
>
> Result: 124.00
>   Here expected is: 123.99

So fraction values are getting rounded. But in my case i dont want it to be rounded. How to stop automatically values getting rounded. Please help me...

Comment: If you are using type="currency" you do not have to specify maxFractionDigits.

Comment: yes i agree. but why it is getting rounded. I don't want to it to be rounded in fractional part.

Comment: please see the cases carefully...

Comment: What exactly do you expect the output to be in these 2 cases? What is the target currency of the format?

Comment: you can use jstl(In JSTL and EL, there is not floor, round, or ceiling function. Here is some relatively uncomplex ways to achieve the same effect.), this post can helps you but you must modify a little; http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/1084/

Comment: I have updated what i am expecting please check

Comment: You appear then to be looking for a Floor function which JSTL does not have. Change to value="${d - 0.005}". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735545/ceiling-of-a-number-in-jstl-el